# mechanize checkbox control not working python

Tags: python, checkbox, mechanize, spam-prevention, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to delete over 2000 spam users of a wikisite, so I used mechanize and user merge and delete (mediawiki extension). the problem I'm encountering is that for deleting, mechanize has to tick a checkbox, which doesn't seem to work:

```
fi = open('users')

for user in fi.readlines():

    response3 = br.open('url')

    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br['olduser'] = user
    br['newuser'] = 'Spambot'
    br.form.find_control(name='deleteuser').items[0].selected = True

    response4 = br.submit()

        print response4.read(), '\njust deleted ', user

fi.close()
```

I've looked in many posts here at stackoverflow as well as other sites, and all say the same

```
br.form.find_control(name='deleteuser').items[0].selected = True
```

should do it.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give URL or html of the page?

Comment: What behaviour do you see?  Have you tried using RobustFactory?

Comment: html is irrelevant, is a link to a form of a mediawiki extension (specialpage:usermergeanddelete).

Comment: the loop doesnt throw exception, it completes as if it was working. It is actually working (filling form an causing a merge of the user references in the SQL database), but the aditional action that is controled by the CheckboxControl is not happening (erasing the merged user from the database) which is the main purpose of the script.

Comment: the command you are executing is correct, so the only thing that can help is the actual html of the form. If you won't supply the page or at least how it works (does it use JavaScript or anything like that to produce the checkbox button) then you won't get any help.

Comment: the reason why the url is irrelevant is because in order to access it, you must be logged in as admin to the site. so even if I supply the url nobody will be able to access it. I don't know if it uses javascript. The form is product of an extension of mediawiki, which is written in PHP. (link <http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:User_Merge_and_Delete> ) @ton1c

Comment: There is no HTML code in the link that you supplied. As I said, if you need help, then supply URL or HTML. IF URL is unavailable(or can't be accessed), then supply the HTML of the URL that you are working on. As stated before command that you have is correct. The only thing that can be issue here, is that you are selecting the checkbox incorrectly, and that's why it's not working.

Comment: Ugh. One ought not need screenscraping for bulk actions in MediaWiki. In fact there is an [open feature request](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T75313). It may be easier for you to [code a script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Writing_maintenance_scripts) using the internal UserMerge functions, than to fiddle with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a solution, but should help you debug and see if you're doing something wrong. The following just prints all the controls on the form you're trying to fill using Mechanize.

```
for control in form[0].controls:
    print control
```

And if you've selected the checkbox correctly it should look like this:

```
<CheckboxControl(deleteorwhatever=[*on])>
```

I hope this helps put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Late but this worked for me...

```
br.find_control("comment_status").items[0].selected = false
```

I didn't specify (name="comment_status") but just the name of it in quotes alone.